# jq: error: xyz/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:

Tags: jq

I have a JSON file with data as below:

```
{
    "servers":{
        "author-name":{
            "server": "app-dv-app01"
        },
        "authorname2":{
            "server": "app-dv-app02"
        }
       }
    }
```

I am trying to access the servername based on the username here from a script with the jq as below:

```
jq .servers.${AUTHOR}.server
```

For **authorname2** it is working fine and returning server app-dv-app02.
But for **author-name** it is throwing error as below. In general I checked that if the Authorname in JSON file contains a "-" then this problem arises.

```
+ AUTHOR=author-name
+ cat dev-servers.json
+ jq .servers.author-name.server
jq: error: name/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.servers.ppataky-unzer.server                 
jq: 1 compile error
```

Could someone please help here to rectify the correct syntax of jq call.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This works jq '.servers."author-name".server' <file-name>

Comment: I have tried this. this doesn't give me a compilation error. However I am using variable to pass value so inside double-quote it is not considering the variable value:         

cat ${ServerList} | jq '.servers."${AUTHOR}".server'


It prints the value as null :

+ AUTHOR=author-name
+ jq .servers."${AUTHOR}".server
+ cat dev-servers.json

echo server: null

Comment: This should work cat file.jq | jq ".servers.\"${AUTHOR}\".server"

Comment: I used this but end up with the same jq compilation error:

 cat <filename> | jq ".servers.\"${AUTHOR}\".server"